# Having trouble with left join SQL in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Short background: I have an SQLite database, a couple of gb in size and growing. It contains a bunch of very simple tables. Each table consists of a 64-bit integer primary index field (TStamp) and a value field (Val). The field TStamp is actually an long-int representation of a date-time. The tables have widely varying row-counts and somewhat variable content types, but that shouldn't matter. A master table (tbIndDate) holds a full range of dates, has the same primary index (TStamp) as the other tables, and holds human-readable date-time in its Val field. For instance,

The master index table, named tbIndDate:

```
TStamp              Val
634082688000000000  5/1/2010 0:00:00
634082691000000000  5/1/2010 0:05:00
634082694000000000  5/1/2010 0:10:00
634082697000000000  5/1/2010 0:15:00
etc                 etc
```

A sample table for automation tag 6FI1.PV, named tb6FI1%PV:

```
TStamp              Val
634085793000000000  41.7 
634085796000000000  42.83 
634085799000000000  41.44 
634085802000000000  40.43 
634085805000000000  39.78 
etc                 etc
```

Getting data into the tables is handled by a little vb.net program, and when a new automation tag is added to the capture list then the program creates a new table using the automation tag name, and begins populating it. That all works real slick.

OK. I've started building a tool for getting data out of the database. It works great for inner joins:

```
SELECT [tbIndDate].[Val] AS 'Timestamp',[tb6FI1%PV].[Val] AS '6FI1.PV',
[tb6FI34%PV].[Val] AS '6FI34.PV',[tb6AI32%PV].[Val] AS '6AI32.PV' 
FROM [tbIndDate],[tb6FI1%PV],[tb6FI34%PV],[tb6AI32%PV] 
WHERE [tbIndDate].[TStamp]=[tb6FI1%PV].[TStamp] 
AND [tbIndDate].[TStamp]=[tb6FI34%PV].[TStamp] 
AND [tbIndDate].[TStamp]=[tb6AI32%PV].[TStamp];
```

This returns:

```
Timestamp          6FI1.PV   6FI34.PV   6AI32.PV
1/1/2013 0:00:00   42.4679   1.499      0.8439
1/1/2013 0:05:00   40.3628   1.5048     0.8435
1/1/2013 0:10:00   38.2652   1.5028     0.8436
1/1/2013 0:15:00   37.8582   1.5029     0.8436
```

Yay! :)

I've also gotten some averaging and time-interval queries working.

However, because tag data is not all available for all dates, I'd like to create the option to list all dates in the master index even if some of the tag tables do not have matching data.

A SELECT query with a left outer join, in other words. Everyone knows that. The data might look like:

```
Timestamp          6FI1.PV   6FI34.PV   6AI32.PV
1/1/2013 0:00:00   42.4679   1.499      NULL
1/1/2013 0:05:00   40.3628   1.5048     NULL
1/1/2013 0:10:00   38.2652   NULL       NULL
1/1/2013 0:15:00   37.8582   NULL       0.8436
```

Trouble is, none of the SQL I've tried has worked. Here's one that didn't go:

```
SELECT [tbIndDate].[Val] AS 'Timestamp',[tb6FI1%PV].[Val] AS '6FI1.PV',
[tb6FI34%PV].[Val] AS '6FI34.PV' 
FROM [tbIndDate],[tb6FI1%PV],[tb6FI34%PV] 
LEFT JOIN [tbIndDate] ON [tbIndDate].[TStamp]=[tb6FI1%PV].[TStamp] 
LEFT JOIN [tbIndDate] ON [tbIndDate].[TStamp]=[tb6FI34%PV].[TStamp];
```

The error was "SQL error or missing database, ambiguous column name: tbIndDate.Val"

I've tried copying the syntax from several examples, but none are exactly the same and my attempts fail.

Am I doing the aliases wrong? The square brackets to accommodate special characters in table names? I'm a complete SQL beginner, so don't hold back with the advice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This seems like a good question, but it is a bit long, which might turn away some answerers. I've removed some blank lines, but perhaps some of the information about what already works isn't necessary, or could be shortened?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome -- I edited out some verbosity. Didn't want my first post to be one of those "not enough info" ones! -- Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you're trying to join `[tbIndDate]` several times. Try this:

```
SELECT [tbIndDate].[Val] AS 'Timestamp',[tb6FI1%PV].[Val] AS '6FI1.PV',
    [tb6FI34%PV].[Val] AS '6FI34.PV' 
FROM [tbIndDate]
LEFT JOIN [tb6FI1%PV] ON [tbIndDate].[TStamp]=[tb6FI1%PV].[TStamp] 
LEFT JOIN [tb6FI34%PV] ON [tbIndDate].[TStamp]=[tb6FI34%PV].[TStamp];
```

Comment: Jeff! That works. I thought every table referenced had to be listed in the FROM clause; not so! And I was using the LEFT JOIN incorrectly. I'll code it, and do some more research so I understand better.